# Ubuntu 20.04 Malformed entry 60 in list file

Tags: apt, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04
The lines in question are:

```
deb http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/toutatis-updates main
# deb-src http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/toutatis-updates main
```

What are these? I am pretty sure they're either Librewolf or Icecat because that was what I was messing with before everything went wrong.

Also, can you help me remove LibreWolf, it won't even start up? I click on it the I get the loading icon and then it stops.

Comment: FYI:   If you open a browser and view attempt to go to that page, you'll quickly discover it doesn't exist. As for why it was added, or what it was added for, I'd ask whomever added it (they have `sudo` rights) as it didn't exist in any release or *flavor* of Ubuntu that is on-topic here.

Comment: I read that, but I didn't know if that would work for what my problem is. Do I just delete it?

Comment: I would probably delete it; as it's incorrect/invalid as it stands, and I can't know what the person whom added it was after when it was added, they didn't do enough checks and should have chosen a better/up-to-date source for whatever they wanted instead of that.  I tend to comment those lines out, but I also comment why I added it, when and leave a trail so in the future me/anyone-else has clues as to reason.. Comment is a "#" at the start of the line

Comment: First, this is MY computer. Second, I just started Linux like a week ago, so I am still working on this stuff. I think it came about when I was working on installing Icecat this morning because that is when this started. The thing is I don't remember doing that part, but I might have done it while try to install Icecat.

Comment: I started using Linux when I was trying to put XUbuntu on a flash drive only to "break" my computer. I install XUbuntu all the way and then couldn't sign in after a couple of times and which to Ubuntu.

Comment: FYI: the date & time of last edit of the file can be viewed with `stat /etc/apt/sources.list` though sources can also be added via any file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (which is an empty directory on a clean install).  For me I also view my `history` (command history) though the default of that doesn't include the date/time each command was executed (I add that as I find it helpful). If you added it via GUI there won't be a command for the add so it won't show in `history`.  If you have issues with your Xubuntu login, ask a new question for that and we'll help (Xubuntu is on-topic here)